# Insert Date field into DB

Tags: java, jsp

I am having a textbox field in my jsp called "req_date". The user is selecting a date from a javascript calendar in the format of "DD-MON-YY" ex. "29-aug-2010".So, now I am stuck while trying to insert it in the DB.

I tried "   String queryString = "INSERT INTO Charity (req_date) VALUES (?)", but it is not inserting. How do I solve tis out.

The req_date is type of date in the DB.

Can you please help

Comment: What database are you using? BTW, why are you using direct JDBC calls and not an ORM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Date format depends upon Database you use.
For reference [Date formats](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-time.html) with Oracle.

**so your query should look like :**

```
String queryString = "INSERT INTO Charity (req_date) VALUES (to_date('29-aug-2010', 'dd-mon-yyyy'))"
```

**This is just to answer your question. But I will prefer usage of PreparedStatement as also suggested in other answers.**

Your code using PreparedStatement should look something like following: (NOTE: I have not tested this code )

```
    String formatIn = "dd-MMM-yyyy";
    SimpleDateFormat sdfi = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
    java.util.Date inDate = sdfi.parse("29-Aug-2010");

    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(inDate.getTime());

    PreparedStatement prest = con
            .prepareStatement("INSERT INTO Charity (req_date) VALUES (?)");
    prest.setDate(1, sqlDate);
    int row = prest.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: How to do that in my previous stetement?

Comment: @maas I have updated your query using to_date() oracle function.

Comment: I have also added solution using preparedStatement. Please have a look

Answer (score 3):

Use a `PreparedStatement` and its `setDate(..)`. Or use a timestamp (`long`).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your database, PostgreSQL does recognize this format:

```
SELECT CAST('29-aug-2010' AS date);
```

Result:

```
'2010-08-29'
```

In most cases, you'd better use the ISO-format yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Depends, you could use TO_DATE() in SQL as YoK showed you or do it in your Java-code.